# How to close angular-ui modal after click button but under condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

I would like to close modal after click button save, but only when function which is also called by this button is resolved successfully.

parent.controller.js

```
.module('app.test')
.controller('TestController', function ($uibModal) {
    let vm = this
    vm.addTest = addTest
    vm.openAddTestModal = openAddTestModal


    function openAddTestModal() {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          component: 'AddTestModalComponent',
          windowClass: 'test-modal',
        })
        modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
            vm.addTest(result);
        });
    }

    function addTest(test) {
        //do something
        if (testCondition) {
            // do something 
               // success - close modal
         } else {
            // error - don't close modal
        }
    }
})
```

modal.component.js

```
.component('AddTestModalComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'app/modals/add-test-modal.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: function ($modalInstance) {
        this.testToSave = [''];
        this.save = function (result) {
            $modalInstance.close(result); 
    //close only function called in parent resolve success
        };
    }
})
```

add-test-modal.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-blue" type="submit"
        ng-click="vm.save(vm.test)">
  Save
</button>
```

Is it possible this way or maybe I should share scope and just call this function from scope parent and then close under condition?

Comment: Component controllers don't work the same way as modal controllers. The `$modalnstance` local is not available in component controllers. See the component example in [UI-Bootstrap $uibModal Service API Reference](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options  can think of assuming addTest returns promise.

1. Move addTest logic to service and call this method from modal controller
2. Pass addTest function as resolve parameter to modal. Please refer https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal

**Parent**

```
function openAddTestModal() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        component: 'AddTestModalComponent',
        windowClass: 'test-modal',
        resolve: {
            addTest: addTest
        }
    })
    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        vm.addTest(result);
    });
}
```

**Modal**

```
controller: function ($modalInstance, addTest) {
    this.testToSave = [''];
    this.save = function (result) {
        addTest().then(function(){
            $modalInstance.close(result);
        })
    };
}
```

.

Comment: Resolvers are functions, not values. As written your resolve will invoke the `addTest` function *before* instantiating the controller. That is a problem if you want to invoke that function with the `save` button.

Comment: Oh yes. Then it should be like this `resolve: {
            addTest: function(){ return addTest;}
        }`